# Drop shadow in knitr

Tags: knitr, beamer, xelatex

I'm mixing knitr, beamer, and xelatex to make some slides to a lecture. I'd like to see my figures dropping shadows in order to make my presentation more fancy.

I found [this great way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81842/creating-a-drop-shadow-with-guassian-blur) to drop shadows from regular figures, but I couldn't make it work inside knitr chunks.

Do you guys know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `fig.show = "hide"` you can prevent `knitr` from including generated figures into your document. This allows you to manually include the figure, using whatever markup you like.

Note that by default figures are stored in the directory `figure` and the file name follows the pattern `chunkname-figurenumber`, e.g. the second figure from `mychunk` has the filename `mychunk-1.pdf`. (See `fig.path` in the chunk options list linked above.)

This leaves us with one last pitfall: The background color of your plot.

> Depending on the graphics packages and devices you use, the background
>   of plots might be transparent (e.g. tikz for base graphics) or white
>   (e.g. **ggplot2**) by default. If you definitely want the
>   background color to be always white for base graphics, you can set up
>   a hook for the `white` option like this:

```
<<white-background,eval=FALSE>>=    
knit_hooks$set(white = function(before, options, envir) {if (before) par(bg = 'white')})
```

(The quote is from an [old version](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/soilDB/vignettes/soilDB-Intro-knitr.Rnw?revision=461&root=aqp&pathrev=461) of the [knitr graphics manual](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/download/doc/knitr-graphics.pdf); I cannot find it in the current version.)

If you need a chunk hook or if setting `par(bg = "white")` is sufficient for you depends on the number of graphs you are generating. If you don't know how to use chunk hooks, take a look at the end of [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157157/2706569).

Not using a chunk hook and adapting the TEX code [from the answer that was linked in the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81847/37118), the following code uses `knitr` to generate a figure with a shadow:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

% code adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11483/3954
% code then adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81847/37118
%
% some parameters for customization
\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}

\colorlet{innercolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!05}

% this draws a shadow under a rectangle node
\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \filldraw ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow}
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mylen

\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{%
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
\setlength\mylen{\wd0}
\ifnum\mylen<\ht0
\setlength\mylen{\ht0}
\fi
\divide \mylen by 120
\def\shadowshift{\mylen,-\mylen}
\def\shadowradius{\the\dimexpr\mylen+\mylen+\mylen\relax}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}


<<myfigure, echo = FALSE, fig.show = "hide">>=
par(bg = "white")
plot(1)
@

\begin{frame}
\shadowimage[width=7cm]{figure/myfigure-1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Figure with shadow.]